# MySQL with HAProxy on same server - How to connect from VIP

Tags: mysql, haproxy

I am running 2 dedicated servers on which each has HAProxy keepalived running, MySQL in master/master and Apache.

Load Balancing for Apache already works, but I can not get MySQL LB running.

HAProxy stats says: DB2 down "access denied for haproxy_check@db2 "

From a tutorial I have learned that I have to prepare mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host,User) values ('10.0.0.10','haproxy_check'); FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

My haproxy config looks like this:

```
listen mysql-cluster
    bind 10.0.0.10:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server db1 10.0.0.120:3307 check
    server db2 10.0.0.130:3307 check
```

Why is HAProxy trying to connect from 10.0.0.130 instead of his VIP 10.0.0.10?

I could of course grant access to 10.0.0.130 but this will ruin the idea of failover. This works by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HAProxy [manual](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html), you can use the `source` keyword to force a `backend` or `listen` block to use a particular IP when connecting to servers.

Your `listen` block would then look like:

```
listen mysql-cluster
  bind 10.0.0.10:3306
  mode tcp
  option mysql-check user haproxy_check
  balance roundrobin
  source 10.0.0.10
  server db1 10.0.0.120:3307 check
  server db2 10.0.0.130:3307 check
```